# Getting email notifications for new questions

Tags: support

I'd like to receive email notifications when new questions are asked on Gardening&Landscaping, but I don't find this setting. Does this setting activate when a certain level of reputation is achieved?
I can subscribe to tags, but it would take a lot of time to subscribe to all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've broken this down into steps (possibly more than is necessary), but hopefully its helpful.

1. Go to [Stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/)
2. Click the [Filtered Questions](http://stackexchange.com/filters/158347/my-filter) tab
3. Under item 1, select 'all questions'
4. Under item 1, select 'just these sites', and type/click on Gardening & Landscaping
5. Under item 2, name your filter (optional)
6. Under item 3, click yes. Make sure the correct email address is shown.
7. Under item 3, choose an option 'every 15 minutes', 'every 3 hours', or 'every day'.
8. Click 'Save Changes'

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really works.

Comment: Thanks for this. There can't ever be too many steps for me!